# there's some error in my code for recursive prime function

Tags: c, recursion, goto

I am supposed to enter a positive number and the terminal should print whether it's prime or not. Also it should ask the user to enter a number repeatedly until the user presses 'q'. It worked fine without goto loop, i.e one at a time.

Can someone tell what's wrong with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

prime(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 1) {
    printf("neither prime nor composite\n");
    return;
  } else if ((a % b) == 0) {
    printf("composite no.\n");
    return;
  } else if (b >= a) {
    printf("prime no.\n");
    return;
  } else
    prime(a, (b + 1));
}

main(void) {
  int x, y = 0, z;
  char a[10], b;
  loops: printf("enter an integer:\t");
  do {
    b = getchar();
    if (b == 'q')
      exit(1);
    x = atoi(&b);
    y = (10 * y) + x;
  } while (b != '\n');
  z = y / 10;
  printf("num is %d and it's\t", z);
  prime(z, 2);
  goto loops;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Also, the compiler does not execute the code. It creates an executable from your source code that can be run.

Comment: Where is `}while();`?

Comment: `atoi(&b);` is [Very bad. Not good. Not good](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.subzin.com%2Fquotes%2FWizards%2FVery%2Bbad.%2BNot%2Bgood.%2BNot%2Bgood&ei=0Tn1UtSAFIiqyAHlkIHYBg&usg=AFQjCNE7XzNQPqMBARmysjBEfIKYGgg-hQ&bvm=bv.60799247,d.aWM) as `b` is a `char` and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize y to 0 at the beginning of your loop

Comment: Is not this initialization `int x, y = 0, z;`?

Comment: yes, but this is only executed before the first iteration. You should put y=0 after the loops: label

Comment: Correct - adding `y=0;` right after the `loops:` label helps. It is not the only problem - the `prime` function doesn't work properly either.

Answer (score 1):

1.We should avoid the use of goto because its just like jump instruction.Upto single goto instruction is OK but when you have multiple then it is difficult to debug the code .

2.the condition of (a==1,we should check in main function and if its true then return.its good in view of CPU usage.

3.should use minimal variable because its is going occupy the memory.So i remove 'b' and 'y' variable.

**Anyway I have some modification in your sample code its may help you.**

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    prime(int a, int b){
    if(b==a){printf("prime no.\n");    return;}
    else if(((a%b) == 0) ){printf("composite no.\n");  return;}
    else    prime(a, (b+1));
    }

    main(void){
    int x, y = 0, z;
    char a[10], b;
    loops:
    printf("enter an integer:\t");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x == -1)    exit(1);
    if( x == 1){printf("neither prime nor composite\n"); return;}
    z=x;
    printf("num is %d and it's\t", z);
    prime(z, 2);
    goto loops;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `goto` if you don't really need it.

To structure your code around not using `goto`, try the following:

```
// ...
char userInput;
do
{
    printf("enter an integer:\t");
    userInput = getchar();
    if (userInput == 'q')
    {
        break;
    }
    // ... perform prime number calculation ...
} while (true); // Continue to loop until the user enters 'q'.
// ...
return 0;
```

This should keep prompting the user for a character until the user has input 'q'.

Comment: the result is same as using goto, it works ok the 1st time, but doesn't fr the 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems. First - the value of `y` needs to be reset to zero for each loop - change lines to:

```
main(void) {
  int x, y, z;
  char a[10], b;
  loops: printf("enter an integer:\t");
  y = 0;    // <<<< add this line
  do {
```

Second, your `prime` function will call a number "composite" when `(a%b==0)` before realizing that `a==b` (from which you conclude correctly that the number is prime). Change the order of the tests as follows:

```
prime(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 1) {
    printf("neither prime nor composite\n");
    return;
  } else if (b >= a) {         // <<<<< do this test first
    printf("prime no.\n");
    return;
  } else if ((a % b) == 0) {
    printf("composite no.\n");
    return;
  } else
    prime(a, (b + 1));
}
```

Third - you are reading a value into a `char`, and then using `atoi(&b)` to convert it to an `int`. This is fraught with danger - you get away with it because it turns out there is nothing in the space after, and the character is "accidentally nul terminated". To be safe, you want to do

```
x = b - '0';
if(x >= 0 && x <= 9) {
  y = (10 * y) + x;
}
```

This converts the character in `b` to a number - and if the character isn't a number, it will skip it and go to the next one. This also means that you no longer need to divide `y` by 10 after the loop.

If you find it still doesn't work, you *may* have a problem with your input buffer. Sometimes there's a spare character in the carriage return (CRLF is really two characters...)

You can add

```
fflush(stdin);
```

before you start reading input (right after `y=0;`).

All these things together lead to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

prime(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 1) {
    printf("neither prime nor composite\n");
    return;
  } else if (b >= a) {
    printf("prime no.\n");
    return;
  } else if ((a % b) == 0) {
    printf("composite no.\n");
    return;
  } else
    prime(a, (b + 1));
}

main(void) {
  int x, y = 0, z;
  char a[10], b;
  loops: printf("enter an integer:\t");
  y = 0;
  fflush(stdin);
  do {
    b = getchar();
    if (b == 'q')
      exit(1);
    x = b - '0';
    if(x >= 0 && x <= 9) {
      y = (10 * y) + x;
    }
  } while (b != '\n');
  printf("num is %d and it's\t", y);
  prime(y, 2);
  goto loops;
  return 0;
}
```

Still not pretty (you really don't want / need a `goto` in this kind of code) but it should work for you. For your next project, learn about the correct way to use `while` loops instead of `goto`...